# Use of @OneToMany or @ManyToMany targeting an unmapped class, unresolved Hibernate error

Tags: mysql, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa, spring-security-oauth2

I am trying to implement Spring Oauth2. All has been good until I keep on getting this error and could not resolve it.

```
import lombok.Data;
import java.util.List;
import javax.persistence.*;

@Entity @Table( name = "role") @Data
public class Role {

    @Id @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Integer id;
    @Column(name = "name")
    private String name;

    public Integer getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(Integer id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public List<Permission> getPermissions() {
        return permissions;
    }

    public void setPermissions(List<Permission> permissions) {
        this.permissions = permissions;
    }

    @ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER, cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @JoinTable(name = "permission_role", joinColumns = { @JoinColumn( name = "role_id", referencedColumnName = "id")},
    inverseJoinColumns = { @JoinColumn(name = "permission_id", referencedColumnName = "id") })
    private List<Permission> permissions;
}
```

The User Model

```
import lombok.Data;

import javax.management.relation.Role;
import javax.persistence.*;
import java.util.List;

@Entity @Table(name = "user") @Data
public class User {

    public User(){}

    public User( User user ){
        this.username = user.getUsername();
        this.password = user.getPassword();
        this.email = user.getEmail();
        this.enabled = user.isEnabled();
        this.accountNonExpired = user.isAccountNonExpired();
        this.accountNonLocked = user.isAccountNonLocked();
        this.credentialsNonExpired = user.isCredentialsNonExpired();
        this.role = user.getRole();
    }

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue( strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Integer id;

    @Column(name = "username")
    private String username;
    @Column(name = "password")
    private String password;
    @Column(name = "email")
    private String email;
    @Column(name = "enabled")
    private boolean enabled;
    @Column(name = "accountNonExpired")
    private boolean accountNonExpired;
    @Column(name = "accountNonLocked")
    private boolean accountNonLocked;
    @Column(name = "credentialsNonExpired")
    private boolean credentialsNonExpired;

    public Integer getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(Integer id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getUsername() {
        return username;
    }

    public void setUsername(String username) {
        this.username = username;
    }

    public String getPassword() {
        return password;
    }

    public void setPassword(String password) {
        this.password = password;
    }

    public String getEmail() {
        return email;
    }

    public void setEmail(String email) {
        this.email = email;
    }

    public boolean isEnabled() {
        return enabled;
    }

    public void setEnabled(boolean enabled) {
        this.enabled = enabled;
    }

    public boolean isAccountNonExpired() {
        return accountNonExpired;
    }

    public void setAccountNonExpired(boolean accountNonExpired) {
        this.accountNonExpired = accountNonExpired;
    }

    public boolean isAccountNonLocked() {
        return accountNonLocked;
    }

    public void setAccountNonLocked(boolean accountNonLocked) {
        this.accountNonLocked = accountNonLocked;
    }

    public boolean isCredentialsNonExpired() {
        return credentialsNonExpired;
    }

    public void setCredentialsNonExpired(boolean credentialsNonExpired) {
        this.credentialsNonExpired = credentialsNonExpired;
    }

    public List<Role> getRole() {
        return role;
    }

    public void setRole(List<Role> role) {
        this.role = role;
    }

    @ManyToMany( fetch = FetchType.EAGER, cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @JoinTable( name = "role_user", joinColumns = { @JoinColumn( name = "user_id", referencedColumnName = "id")},
    inverseJoinColumns = { @JoinColumn( name = "role_id", referencedColumnName = "id") })
    private List<Role> role;
}
```

I am trying to implement ManyToMany relationship between the 2 Models
I kept on getting this error

```
Caused by: org.hibernate.AnnotationException: Use of @OneToMany or @ManyToMany targeting an unmapped class: io.christdoes.authentication.model.User.role[javax.management.relation.Role]
    at org.hibernate.cfg.annotations.CollectionBinder.bindManyToManySecondPass(CollectionBinder.java:1274) ~[hibernate-core-5.3.10.Final.jar:5.3.10.Final]
    at org.hibernate.cfg.annotations.CollectionBinder.bindStarToManySecondPass(CollectionBinder.java:811) ~[hibernate-core-5.3.10.Final.jar:5.3.10.Final]
    at org.hibernate.cfg.annotations.CollectionBinder$1.secondPass(CollectionBinder.java:736) ~[hibernate-core-5.3.10.Final.jar:5.3.10.Final]
    at org.hibernate.cfg.CollectionSecondPass.doSecondPass(CollectionSecondPass.java:54) ~[hibernate-core-5.3.10.Final.jar:5.3.10.Final]
    at org.hibernate.boot.internal.InFlightMetadataCollectorImpl.processSecondPasses(InFlightMetadataCollectorImpl.java:1696) ~[hibernate-core-5.3.10.Final.jar:5.3.10.Final]
    at org.hibernate.boot.internal.InFlightMetadataCollectorImpl.processSecondPasses(InFlightMetadataCollectorImpl.java:1664) ~[hibernate-core-5.3.10.Final.jar:5.3.10.Final]
    at org.hibernate.boot.model.process.spi.MetadataBuildingProcess.complete(MetadataBuildingProcess.java:287) ~[hibernate-core-5.3.10.Final.jar:5.3.10.Final]
    at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.metadata(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:904) ~[hibernate-core-5.3.10.Final.jar:5.3.10.Final]
    at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.build(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:935) ~[hibernate-core-5.3.10.Final.jar:5.3.10.Final]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.SpringHibernateJpaPersistenceProvider.createContainerEntityManagerFactory(SpringHibernateJpaPersistenceProvider.java:57) ~[spring-orm-5.1.9.RELEASE.jar:5.1.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.createNativeEntityManagerFactory(LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:365) ~[spring-orm-5.1.9.RELEASE.jar:5.1.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.buildNativeEntityManagerFactory(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:390) ~[spring-orm-5.1.9.RELEASE.jar:5.1.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:377) ~[spring-orm-5.1.9.RELEASE.jar:5.1.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:341) ~[spring-orm-5.1.9.RELEASE.jar:5.1.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1837) ~[spring-beans-5.1.9.RELEASE.jar:5.1.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1774) ~[spring-beans-5.1.9.RELEASE.jar:5.1.9.RELEASE]
    ... 16 common frames omitted
```

Comment: looks like you have not listed the `Role` entity in configure your session factory, so make sure if the package in Role is being listed, if you move in User `package` it will be resolved.

Comment: @halfer, thanks for the professional suggestion. I'll stick to it.